# Check the existence of remote directory with R

Tags: r

I would like to check whether a given directory exists in a remote server, given the URL pointing to that directory. For example:

```
url <- "http://plasmodb.org/common/downloads/release-24"
```

How can this be accomplished in R? I have considered using `url.show`, which downloads and shows the url if it exists but gives an error in the case of a non-existent directory. But I am not sure what would be the best approach, optimally without having to download the whole URL in the case of an existing directory.

Comment: have you tried `?file.exists` ?

Comment: @tospig yes. It doesn't work. `file.exists(url)` returns `FALSE` but it should be `TRUE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be highly dependent on the server/resource in question since it has more to do with HTTP status codes than R capability. Provided a remote server is configured to respond properly to directory index requests you can use `HEAD` from `httr` for this:

```
library(httr)

status <- HEAD("http://plasmodb.org/common/downloads/release-24/")
status$status_code
## [1] 200

status <- HEAD("http://plasmodb.org/common/downloads/release-100/")
status$status_code
## [1] 404
```

Here's a nicely-formatted list of status codes http://httpstatus.es and here's a salient RFC http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html that you should also peruse other sections of. Finally, here's a Wikipedia link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index discussing the "directory index". That shows you may also get a `403` vs `200` or `404` depending on the config (and it's really not limited to that depending on the web server).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and extended information. It seems there is not a general approach (as you mention it depends on the server configuration). In my case I want to access that particular server, so hopefully things will keep consistent over time. I may try other ways to solve my problem, but this is very useful knowledge anyway.